# Deriving the general equation for a parabola.

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I fail to derive the parabola equation from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2266385/942378), which states that the general equation of any conic section is

$\tag{0} ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f=0$

where for a parabola we have $ab-c^2=0$ [2].

I operate with the parabola definition $\tag{1} \|X-F\| = distance(X, L)$, where $F=(f, g)$ is the focus point, $X=(x, y)$ is a point on the parabola, $L = \{Y  | (Y-P)N=0\}$ is the directrix line, $N = (a, b)$ is unit-vector normal to the directrix, $P=(p,q)$ is a point on the directrix.

$distance(X,L) = |(X-P)N| = |(x-p, y-q)(a,b)| = |a(x-p) + b(y-q)|$

If I plug that back into $1$, I get:

$\sqrt{(x-f)^2 + (y-g)^2} = |a(x-p) + b(y-q)| \implies$
$(x-f)^2 + (y-g)^2 = (a(x-p) + b(y-q))^2 \implies$
$\tag{2} x^2 (a^2-1) + y^2(b^2-1) + 2abxy + k_1x + k_2y + k_3 = 0$

Where $k_1, k_2, k_3$ are some constants, which are not important for this discussion.

If we take an example parabola: $x^{2}-4xy+4y^{2}+40x+20y=100$, it would not fit into the equation $2$, but it also does *not* satisfy the initial condition of $1\cdot4 - 4^2=0$

What I'm doing wrong here?

---

[2]: The correct condition is $4ab-c^2=0$, but I left the original text of the question for posterity, even though after reading the answers here I realized that the referenced answer was wrong.

Comment: What you got *is* a parabola and the condition should be $\color{red}4ab=c^2$.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos! But how can I fit that parabola equation to the example parabola?

$a^2 - 1 = 1 \implies a = \pm \sqrt 2, b^2 - 1 = 4 \implies b = \pm \sqrt 5, 2ab = \pm 2 \sqrt 10 \ne -4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, $x^2-4xy+4y^2+40x+20y=100$ is a parabola and there is no problem here, since the correct condition is $\color{red}4ab=c^2$.

On the other hand, note that\begin{multline}x^2-4xy+4y^2+40x+20y-100=\\=-5\left(\left(\left(\frac2{\sqrt5}\right)^2-1\right)x^2+2\frac2{\sqrt5}\frac1{\sqrt5}xy+\left(\left(\frac1{\sqrt5}\right)^2-1\right)y^2-8x-4y+20\right).\end{multline}Since $\left(\frac2{\sqrt5}\right)^2+\left(\frac1{\sqrt5}\right)^2=1$, this is indeed a parabola. You did not take into consideration the possibility of multiplying the expression of a parabola by a constant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I had no doubt that $x^{2}-4xy+4y^{2}+40x+20y=100$ is a parabola. I'm looking for a way to get to the general equation of parabola, and a condition which I can use to test if an equation represents a parabola or not (e.g. $4ab=c^2$). Is my equation $2$ in the question wrong? If it's correct, how come it cannot fit that example parabola (scaling it by a constant does not change $4ab=c^2$ condition)? If it's wrong, where did I go astray?

Comment: Your formula is *not* wrong. It turns out that the general expression of a quadric that represents a parabola is$$\lambda\left((a^2-1)x^2+(b^2-1)y^2+2abxy+k_1x+k_2y+k_3\right)=0,$$where $a^2+b^2=1$ and $k_1$, $k_2$, and $k_3$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense now. The condition $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ in my equation $2$ is equivalent to the usual condition of $4ab = c^2$ in equation $0$. However, is $x^2 - 4xy + 4y^2 = 0$ also a parabola? It satisfies the condition, but it seems that it's not a parabola, because $y=\frac{x}{2}$ is just a straight line. If $4ab = c^2$ is not a sufficient condition, should I open a new question, or get it all done here?

Comment: That's a degenerate conic, not a parabola. It's similar to $x^2+y^2=a$. Is it a circle? Yes, if $a>0$. But it's just a point  (which is a degenerate conic) if $a=0$ and it is the empty set if $a<0$. But, yes, you are right: $4ab=c^2$ is not a sufficient condition for having a parabola.

Comment: I understand, but I'm looking for a sufficient condition to have a parabola, not any arbitrary conic section, so I would appreciate if you could help me get there. (I'm trying to solve exercise $13.25.15$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. $1$, and for that I need to know how a collection of all parabolas looks like, and then prove that it's closed under similarity transforms -- i.e. that the condition still holds after the similarity transform.)

Comment: At least we seem to agree that $4ab = c^2$ is *not* a sufficient condition to have a parabola.

Comment: Posted a follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4731104/942378

Answer (score 1):

SOME HINTS:

We are discussing a situation where the parabola axis of symmetry is not parallel to either of the two coordinate axes.

$$ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f=0 \tag1 $$

where its discriminant $ 4ab-c^2=0 $ of the quadratic vanishes $ \tag 2 $

Plug in

$$ax^2+by^2\pm 2 \sqrt{ab}+dx+ey+f=0 \tag3 $$

for all values of constant coefficients. What do you call these types of equations?

Can you see two parabola segments represented here?

There are 5 unknown constants; any conic is determined if 5 points are given. If you divide throughout by $f,$ remaining 4 constants suffice for a solution.

Solving a quadratic the two equation can be also cast into form:

$$ y =kx+ly\pm \sqrt{mx+ny} \tag 4 $$

When the quantity under radical sign vanishes, there  is common tangent point parallel to y-axis for the two parabolas.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm looking for a way to get to the general equation of parabola, and a condition which I can use to test if an equation represents a parabola or not (e.g. $4ab=c^2$).

Comment: Equation 3 represents  all parabolas in $x-y$ plane.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**- The notations used are slightly different.

Firstly, the locus of a point which moves on a plane such that the ratio of its distance from a fixed point to its perpendicular distance from a fixed straight line is a conic. The fixed point is the focus and the fixed line is called the directrix of the conic. This ratio is called the eccentricity $e$ and for a parabola $e=1$.The general equation of a conic as stated;

$$ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c=0$$

A parabola can be defined when;

(1)$$\frac{SP}{PM}=1$$

(repeating what is said above), Here $SP$ represents the distance of the focus $S(\alpha,\beta)$ of the conic and any point $P(x,y)$ and $PM$ represents the perpendicular distance of the same point $P(x,y)$ from a fixed line known as the directrix.

(2)

When the determinant of the coefficients, $\Delta=\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & h & g  \\
h & b & f  \\
g  & f  & c   \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}≠0$,

(3)

For a parabola, $h^2=ab$

Now using your given example, $x^2+4y^2-4xy+40x+20y-100=0$;

on comparing gives the values; $a=1$, $b=4$, $h=-2$, $g=20$, $f=10$ and $c=-100$.

Substituting in condition; $h^2=ab$, we get 4=4, hence proving, the conic is a parabola.

Continuing (1),

Refer the below image(apologies for including an image) for the better understanding, The focus is $S(\alpha,\beta)$, the point $P(x,y)$ and the fixed line aka the Directrix is $a'x+b'y+c'=0$, where a',b' and c' are  constants; (not to be confused with a,b and c of the general equation of a conic).

Now for a parabola as we saw in (1), $\frac{SP}{PM}=e=1$, substitute SP as $\left|\sqrt{(x-\alpha)^2+(y-\beta)^2)}\right|$  and PM as $\left|\frac{a'x+b'y+c}{\sqrt{(a')^2+(b')^2}}\right|$, If on verifying with your given example by rearranging into this format to get e=1, we can conclude it is a parabola.

Given; $x^2+4y^2-3xy+40x+20y-100=0$, we can rewrite it as the focus-directrix form as mentioned above;

$$\sqrt {x^2+y^2}=\frac{(2x+y-10)}{\sqrt5}$$

we can observe, $e=1$ (as no extra constant is present that supports this equality) and this concludes your example is a parabola with focus $(0,0)$, the directrix is $2x+y=10$, and vertex is $(2,1)$

[image]

For last line defense, The given example can be concluded as a parabola when $\Delta ≠ 0$ (as seen in (2) ), which you can easily verify (carefully compare the coefficients).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I had no doubt that $x^{2}-4xy+4y^{2}+40x+20y=100$ is a parabola. I'm looking for a way to get to the general equation of parabola, and a condition which I can use to test if an equation represents a parabola or not (e.g. $4ab=c^2$).

Comment: Yes, but without derivation, and I'm looking for knowing how to get there...is it possible to use my equation $2$ from the question?

Comment: I am assuming there is some language barrier here, in your question, the last line claims the equation is not a parabola, so to prove it otherwise i have stated various ways and definitions above. Moreover, what you have done in your equation 2 is the same as what i have done in my step 1(continuation part), which is a continuation to your step 2 (with fewer constants), moreover the condition you have mentioned $ab=c^2$ is incorrect and it has to be $4ab=c^2$

Comment: Yes, your equation 2 is right and is quite similar to mine. The only issue is in your condition that can decide for equation to show a parabola or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another form to handle the parabola.

Given the parabola directrix

$$
p = p_0 + \lambda \vec v,\ \ \ \|\vec v\|=1
$$

and  the focus $f$, with $q = (x,y)'$, the parabola has the property:

$$
\|f-q\|^2=\|q-p_0-((q-p_0)\cdot\vec v)\vec v\|^2
$$

so developing and grouping terms we arrive at

$$
q'\cdot(\vec v\cdot\vec v')\cdot q-2(f+(\vec v\cdot\vec v'-I_2)\cdot p_0)\cdot q+\|f\|^2-p_0'\cdot (\vec v\cdot\vec v'-I_2)\cdot p_0=0
$$

here

$$
\vec v\cdot\vec v'=\left(\matrix{v_x^2&v_xv_y\\ v_xv_y & v_y^2}\right)\\ I_2=\left(\matrix{1&0\\ 0 & 1}\right)
$$