# solving geometric problems analyticially by fitting a coordinate system to them

Tags: analytic-geometry

I encountered a few problems where it is quite helpful to fit the coordinate system to the problem, and I wanted to check here if that's a sound thing to do.

For example, in Tom Apostol's Calculus ex. $13.25.15$ we should prove that the collection of all parabolas is invariant under a similarity transform.

Coming up with a general parabola equation is hard ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4731104/942378)), and I would much rather approach the problem like this:

1. Take any parabola.
2. Take the coordinate system such that the axis of the parabola is the X axis, and the directrix is parallel to the Y axis.
3. In such a coordinate system we know the equation of the parabola to be $\tag{1} (y-y_0)^2 = 4c_0(x-x_0)$
4. In $1$, we replace $x$ with $tx$ and $y$ with $ty$ to see that we still have a parabola $(y-y_1)^2 = 4c_1(x-x_1)$.

Is that a correct *analytic* solution?
Is there a more analytical solution?
Is there some caution I should be aware of when fitting in coordinate system to similar problems?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty easy to make completely analytic. Find a coordinate transformation between the two different planes

Comment: @SBrian Thanks! I suppose the two different planes are $P_1, P_2$ with coordinate system axis $P_1=\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ and $P_2=\{(a,b), (c,d)\}$, where $(a,b)$ is the parabola axis wrt $P_1$, and $(c,d)$ a vector parallel to the directrix wrt $P_1$. However, I still don't understand why do we even need that, and what prevents us from starting right away with that coordinate system $P_2$, with parabola vertex at $(0,0)$ wrt $P_2$? If possible, it would be nice if you can provide a full answer, so we can also close the question.